# Почему Php не показывает ошибки?

Tags: php, apache

Правлю файл который указан в phpinfo():

```
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

В phpinfo() выдает

```
display_errors  On  On
display_startup_errors  On  On
html_errors On  On
log_errors  On  On
log_errors_max_len  1024    1024
```

в .htaccess пробовал включать ошибки, не работает
Если написать кривой sql запрос, то выводится белый экран.
Ошибка mysql выводится, если перед запросом вызвать функцию:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Если написать функцию с ошибкой

```
function a($x,y){ return $x+$y; }
```

выводится пустой экран.
Сервер локальный,  ubuntu16.04 apache2 php7 mysql5.7
Настроен виртуальный хост

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html 
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory "/var/www/example.com/public_html">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Как сделать так, чтоб выводились ошибки?

Answer (score 1):

"выводится пустой экран. Сервер локальный, ubuntu16.04 apache2 php7 mysql5.7 Настроен виртуальный хост, Как сделать так, чтоб выводились ошибки?" любой каприз за ваши деньги:)

```
function setVisibleServerError($bool, $notice = false){
    if($bool){
        ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
        if($notice == true)error_reporting(E_ALL);
        else error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
    }else {
        ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
    }
}
```

Шлите ей (true, false) означает показывать ошибки, но не показывать незначительные ошибки, (true, true) показывать все ошибки. Но, учтите если проблема с синтаксисом, то пхп анализ не будет ничего выполнять и просто выбросит вам ошибку(а если отключено в php.ini то нече не выбросит:), а покажет белое)(делайте так, основной файл, сетим ошибку, подключаем include и все работает)

Comment: Какой командой отключается\включается вывод ошибок синтаксиса?

Comment: "Какой командой отключается\включается вывод ошибок синтаксиса?" я вам дал совет, делайте обертку. Тоесть тестовый скрипт, в нем стоит эта функция с true, false, дальше Include и вы увидите ошибки синтаксиса! А если допустите ошибку синтаксиса в файле где делается эта функция true, false, то она не поможет, так как пхп не выполнится!!

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка (исключение) компиляции и естественно ничего на экран не выведет. Исключения компиляции можно отлавливать в 7 версии через `try-catch`. Попробуйте написать что-то типа этого `echo $arr[test];`.

Comment: Не правда. php скрипт не компилируеться. А человек правит видимо php.ini клиента... И кто плюсует такие ответы.

Comment: @Naumov это я плюсанул. Потому что php это Интерпретатор компилирующего типа. Смотри википедию. И че значит правлю php.ini у клиента? У меня сервер локально развернут.

Comment: @A50 php в командной строке это клиент, на фронте это cgi,fpm,mod_php и т.д., плюс php интерпритатор имеет pool'ы(fpm), плюс есть деректива `error_reporting`, у вас вообще пишуться ошибки в лог? в общем много вопросов. На счёт ошибок компиляции, php проводит лексический анализ кода -> потом синтаксический -> компилирует его в байт код -> выполняет. Вот если там произошла ошибка в компиляции это будет баг php интерпритатора.

Comment: Если я в файле php напишу глупость, он мне белый экран выдает в браузере вместо ошибки,при чем тут командная строка? В вопросе указано же, что правлю конфигурацию сервера. 
директива error_reporting E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE 32767

Comment: "Исключения компиляции можно отлавливать в 7 версии через try-catch" и в версии 5.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно на компьютере установлено несколько версий PHP, а Сервер работает на другой версии. Проверяем верисию PHP сервера `phpinfo();` и находим именно тот PHP.INI той версии. Часто когда на компьютере несколько версий, люди меняют не в тех настройках. Когда то сам сталкивался с такой проблемой.